# Unity back button

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity app for android and want to implement back button functionality.I am using Unity 2019.1.11f1

I added an empty game object and attached a script to it which I have attached below.

```
public class BackButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the app to quit but nothing happens.I also tried using GetKey and GetKeyUp instead of GetKeyDown.

Comment: did you try to add some Logs or something to see which of your checks is the one failing?

Comment: This all looks correct to me. Make sure the update function is actually running, and that Unity is picking it up as Android.

Try to `Debug.Log(Application.platform)` in Start() and see if it gives you android

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: Problem is solved ...